# Updating user profile after user create in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I've extended the user object using the 1.4x method by adding a custom "profile" model and then instantiating it on user save/create. During my registration process I'd like to add additional information to the profile model. The view successfully renders, but the profile model doesn't save. Code below:

```
    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'])
    user.save()

    profile = user.get_profile()
    profile.title = request.POST['title']
    profile.birthday = request.POST['birthday']

    profile.save()
```

Comment: Hey Catherine, Sorry. I should have said thank you first. I appreciate your answer. I would totally use the request.user method, but since I'm registering the user in the same function as the changes to the profile, using the request object won't work.

Comment: Ok why not call it in other way, `profile=Profile(user=user)`

Comment: Are you sure that `user.get_profile()` returns a Profile ? Also I think that catherine ment to `profile=Profile.objects.get(user=user)`

Comment: What does `get_profile()` return? 
@PepperoniPizza No. @catherine is creating a new Profile instance. You're trying to get an instance that's already been created.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the confusion, and I appreciate the help. I'm using the standard method for extending the user, by creating with a OneToOne field and instantiating it on user create. Because of this, it should be created when I save() the user model. But, it doesn't seem to exist. For some reason, selecting it using Profile.objects.filter(user=user) works, and I've managed to solve the problem with the update() method. #dumbbugs

Answer (score 6):

update your models.py with this code

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

now when you do

user.save()

it will automatically create a profile object. then you can do

```
user.profile.title = request.POST['title']
user.profile.birthday = request.POST['birthday']
user.profile.save()
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me a lot! :) I have two questions about it: 1) I think that you assign the function to `profile` in `profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)` because you want to use it later on in `user.profile.title = request.POST['title']`. Correct? Then why do you need `created`? And 2) In the connect part, shouldn't I need a `weak=False` like this: `post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, weak=False)`? Thanks!

Comment: you need created because get_or_create() function returns you a tuple, not an object, like this ... object, True = get_or_create()

Answer (score 1):

user is an instance of User model. And it is seems like you are trying to get an instance which is already exists. It depends on what you returning from user.get_profile. You have to initiate UserProfile instance. The simpler way could be like this:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
user_profile.title = request.POST['title']
...
.
.
user_profile.save()
```